# Textarea is empty in mySQL database field PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

i created an HTML form and trying to save the data from its fields to the database. Inputs, drop-down menus and radio button are stored correctly however the textarea is always added to the database as empty field. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="feedback_form_style.css">
</head>
<form name="feedbackform" method="post" class="basic-grey" action="feedback_form_send.php">
<h1>Feedback form
    <span>Please answer the questions below.</span>
</h1>
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="School">School</label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="School" placeholder="Name of your school" maxlength="50" size="30" required/> <! required not supported in Safari>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="Year">Year</label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="Year" placeholder="Which year you are" maxlength="50" size="30"/>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="Gender">Gender</label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <select name="Gender">
            <option value="male"/>Male</option>
            <option value="female"/>Female</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<p></p> <!emptyline>

<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="What do you think and engineer does">What do you think an engineer does? </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <textarea name="What do you think an engineer does" placeholder="Your answer here" maxlength="1000" cols="60" rows="10"/></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr> <td><p></p></td></tr> <!emptyline>

<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="What was the most enjoyable part about the visit today?">What was the most enjoyable part about the visit today? </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <textarea name="What was the most enjoyable part about the visit today" placeholder="Your answer here" maxlength="1000" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr> <td><p></p></td></tr> <!emptyline>

<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="Was there anything you did not like?">Was there anything you did not like? </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <input type="radio" name="Was there anything you did not like?" value="yes">Yes (plese give details below)
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="Was there anything you did not like?" value="no">No
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <textarea name="Was there anything you did not like (comment)?" placeholder="Details here" maxlength="1000" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr> <td><p></p></td></tr> <!emptyline>

<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="Would you consider studying Engineering at university?">Would you consider studying Engineering at university? </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <input type="radio" name="Would you consider studying Engineering at university?" value="yes">Yes
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="Would you consider studying Engineering at university?" value="no">No
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="Would you consider studying Engineering at university?" value="unsure">Unsure
    </td>
</tr>

<tr> <td><p></p></td></tr> <!emptyline>

<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="Has today's session inspired you to consider becoming an engineer?">Has today's session inspired you to consider becoming an engineer? </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <input type="radio" name="Has today's session inspired you to consider becoming an engineer?" value="yes">Yes
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="Has today's session inspired you to consider becoming an engineer?" value="no">No
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="Has today's session inspired you to consider becoming an engineer?" value="unsure">Unsure
    </td>
</tr>

<tr> <td><p></p></td></tr> <!emptyline>

<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="Before today's session did you know much about engineering?">Before today's session did you know much about engineering? </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <input type="radio" name="Before today's session did you know much about engineering?" value="yes">Yes
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="Before today's session did you know much about engineering?" value="no">No
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="Before today's session did you know much about engineering?" value="unsure">A little
    </td>
</tr>

<tr> <td><p></p></td></tr> <!emptyline>

<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="Has todays session taught you much about engineering?">Has todays session taught you much about engineering? </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <input type="radio" name="Has todays session taught you much about engineering?" value="yes">Yes
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="Has todays session taught you much about engineering?" value="no">No
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="Has todays session taught you much about engineering?" value="unsure">A little
    </td>
</tr>

<tr> <td><p></p></td></tr> <!emptyline>

<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="Based on today's session, what do you think an engineer does?">Based on today's session, what do you think an engineer does? </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <textarea name="Based on today's session, what do you think an engineer does?" placeholder="Your answer here" maxlength="1000" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr> <td><p></p></td></tr> <!emptyline>

<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="Comments/Suggestions/Questions">Comments/Suggestions/Questions </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <textarea name="Comments/Suggestions/Questions" placeholder="Enter your comments, suggestions and questions here" maxlength="1000" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr> <td><p></p></td></tr> <!emptyline>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
        Thank you for your feedback
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
        © Girls in Engineering 2015
    </td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

PHP:

```
$value = test_input($_POST['School']);
$value2 = test_input($_POST['What do you think an engineer does']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO form1 (input1,input2) VALUES ('$value', '$value2')";

if($_POST){
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
}
```

Output from print_r($_POST):

```
Array
(
    [School] => 123
    [Year] => 
    [Gender] => male
    [What_do_you_think_an_engineer_does] => 234
    [What_was_the_most_enjoyable_part_about_the_visit_today] => 
    [Was_there_anything_you_did_not_like_(comment)?] => 
    [Based_on_today's_session,_what_do_you_think_an_engineer_does?] => 
    [Comments/Suggestions/Questions] => 
)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the `test_input()` function is working correctly? Try debugging its return value. `var_dump($data)` or `print_r($data)`

Comment: You can not do this: `<textarea type="text"`, try just `<textarea `

Comment: @Chris test_input function works fine for other type of fields, but for textarea it does not print anything.

Comment: @Rasclatt i deleted type="text", still does not work

Comment: Can you show whole form?

Comment: Also does anything show up in raw print of post?: `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: If you are sure you are receiving input from the textarea via `$_POST`, then I would look at the `htmlspecialchars` function. It does not always play nice.

Comment: Try adding a `/` at the end of the first input: `<input type="text" name="School" placeholder="Name of your school" maxlength="50" size="30" required /> `

Comment: Shouldn't the SQL stmt be like: INSERT INTO form1 (Comment) VALUES (''.$comment.'')

Comment: print_r prints the value for School but nor for Comments.

Comment: Did you try the forward slash on the `School` input?

Comment: @Rasclatt yes. school input is correctly stored in the database.

Comment: I know but you added the forward slash to the end of that input as I noted above? That indicates a stop essentially for that input.

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes I did. Nothing changed

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` shouldn't be used to escape and/or convert html characters when inserting into a database. Rather you should use Prepared Statements to safely insert rows in a database and use `htmlspecialchars` only when reading from database and printing to screen.

Comment: Your form works fine with all those changes, so it's on your PHP side.

Comment: @Rasclatt even if try `echo $_POST['Comments']` or `print_r($_POST['Comments'])` it does not print anything. Looks like it cannot even retrieve the text from a textarea.

Comment: Try to insert without the function `test_input` and see if work.

Comment: I tested your form as you posted and it posts with proper values populated. Is there more that may influence what you are doing?

Comment: You must have stuff missing since you have no submit button in your example. Is there more that's left out that could possibly be messing with that one field?

Comment: @Rasclatt My whole form was huge. So i tried to make it easier. I now edited the question and added the complete form.

Comment: This form doesn't have a field with that name (`Comments`). Has one named `Comments/Suggestions/Questions` though. You would need `$_POST['Comments/Suggestions/Questions']`, which is not the best of key names... :)

Comment: where are you fetching the post 'Comments'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `name="Comments"` in the textarea. as that is what the `$_POST['Comments']` is linked to.

Suppose your code have

```
<textarea name="What was the most enjoyable part about the visit today" placeholder="Your answer here" maxlength="1000" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
```

your post should be `$_POST['What was the most enjoyable part about the visit today']`

if you want to pass Comments as an array

```
<textarea name="Comments[]" placeholder="Your answer here" maxlength="1000" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Hint: Use thed code below for debugging on the page feedback_form_send.php to check what values were sent to it through post on submit;

```
if($_POST){
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
}
```

EDITED

Advice: Your code is vulnerable to Sql injection. use PDO or mysqli instead of mysql

EDITED

my print shows with values

```
Array
(
    [School] => myschool
    [Year] => 2018
    [Gender] => male
    [What_do_you_think_an_engineer_does] => engineer sleeps
    [What_was_the_most_enjoyable_part_about_the_visit_today] => it was nice
    [Was_there_anything_you_did_not_like?] => yes
    [Was_there_anything_you_did_not_like_(comment)?] => too beutiful
    [Would_you_consider_studying_Engineering_at_university?] => yes
    [Has_today's_session_inspired_you_to_consider_becoming_an_engineer?] => no
    [Before_today's_session_did_you_know_much_about_engineering?] => unsure
    [Has_todays_session_taught_you_much_about_engineering?] => yes
    [Based_on_today's_session,_what_do_you_think_an_engineer_does?] => engineers do hard work
    [Comments/Suggestions/Questions] => no comments, i suggest to do things
)
```

So Your php variables should be assigned something like this. **This is just a demonstration to make it understandable. Always do remember to sanitize the input before using**

```
    $school=$_POST['School'];
    $year=$_POST['Year'];
    $gender=$_POST['Gender'];
    $whatengineerdoes=$_POST['What_do_you_think_an_engineer_does'];
    $enjoyable_part=$_POST['What_was_the_most_enjoyable_part_about_the_visit_today'];
    $youdontlike=$_POST['Was_there_anything_you_did_not_like?'];
    $didnotlike=$_POST['Was_there_anything_you_did_not_like_(comment)?'];
    $wouldyou=$_POST['Would_you_consider_studying_Engineering_at_university?'];
    $session_inspired=$_POST["Has_today's_session_inspired_you_to_consider_becoming_an_engineer?"];
    $before_session=$_POST["Before_today's_session_did_you_know_much_about_engineering?"];
    $has_taught=$_POST['Has_todays_session_taught_you_much_about_engineering?'];
    $based_on=$_POST["Based_on_today's_session,_what_do_you_think_an_engineer_does?"];
    $comments=$_POST['Comments/Suggestions/Questions'];
```

EDITED

HERE is example how you can insert the above data into your table

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "mydatabase";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "mypppasss";
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbusername,$dbpassword);
$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO form1(input1,input2,input3,input4,input5,input6,input7,input8,input9,input10,input11,input12,input13)
    VALUES(:inp1,:inp2,:inp3,:inp4,:inp5,:inp6,:inp7,:inp8,:inp9,:inp10,:inp11,:inp12,:inp13)");
$statement->execute(array(
    inp1=>$school,
    inp2=>$year,
    inp3=>$gender,
    inp4=>$whatengineerdoes,
    inp5=>$enjoyable_part,
    inp6=>$youdontlike,
    inp7=>$didnotlike,
    inp8=>$wouldyou,
    inp9=>$session_inspired,
    inp10=>$before_session,
    inp11=>$has_taught,
    inp12=>$based_on,
    inp13=>$comments
));
```

Comment: Debugging function prints all the values I entered in the form. however only first three of them (up to gender) are stored in the database.

Comment: could you add what you get though print_r and your insert query to the question :)

Comment: @user2758935 edited answer. see whether it solves :)

Comment: wc @user2758935 see i have edited again to introduce you to PDO. that's safe way to query to database . good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$comment = test_input($_POST['Comments']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO form1 (Comment) VALUES ('$comment')";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually won't help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Please never do this, as it opens up for an extreme case of SQL injection!