# html text form with php isn't inserting into MySQL server

Tags: php, html, mysql, form-submit

[image: output + code]

I am writing code that produces a `<textarea>` for a user to input something but it isn't giving me any output besides "please include some content" which is what it means to do if there is nothing in the box.  This appears even if there is content in the `<textarea>` and won't even say "post fail" which is what it is meant to do if it can't insert into the database.

I am asking if anybody can see if there is something I have neglected to include, or if there is something that is wrong with my code.

```
<?php
session_start();
require('connect.php');
if(@$_SESSION["name"]){
    //echo "welcome ".$_SESSION['name'];
 ?>
  <html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<head>
<title> Welcome to faecesbook</title>
</head>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <form action="post.php" method="POST">
        <br / >
        <br / >
        <br / >
        <br / >
    <center>
        <br/> 
        <br/>
        Type your post here:<br/>(160CharLimit)<br/>
        <textarea style="resize: none;  width: 800px; height: 100px;" name="con" maxlength="160">
       </textarea>
                     <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" style="width: 800px;" >
    </center>   
    </form>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<?php       
$content = @$_POST['con'];
$post_date = date("d-m-y");


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($content){
        if($query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO post(`postID`, `userID`   , `post_date` , `in_reply_to`, `postContent` ) 
        VALUES ('','".$_SESSION["userID"]."','".$post_date."','','".$content."')") )
            echo "post successful";
        }else{
            echo "post fail";
}   

    }else{
        echo "Please include some content";
    }
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: See my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470932/textarea-is-empty-in-mysql-database-field-php/32471579#32471579 . hope it helps :)

Comment: i just read your answer, which part of your answer can help me ? i cant find it

Comment: last part. Let me brief :)

Comment: ok iam still confused

Comment: you could also construct the statement as a seperate string and echo it out to be able to inspect it and even try to run the statement in phpmyadmin of your mysql database directly to verify that the statement is valid

Comment: So it's failing after outputting the HTML. You have error reporting on? What does it tell you?

Comment: dont put @ in front of your SESSIOn and POST .. that suppresses error messages

Comment: What @DTH means is use `isset()` to prevent notices instead of suppressing them with @

Comment: I added a photo up to show whats the output is like. 

So it just skipping the first parts and going to the last "else" part

Comment: @30088121: you are also missing a closing bracket for if(@$_SESSION["name"]){

Comment: I tried with isset() and it does the same thing, doesnt show errors. Just goes to the else statement that says to put some content in the textarea

Comment: That was just advice. Not using isset() has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I just getting so frustrated, because i have structured and used the same ways to code the page as other pages that did not have this problem and worked fine with inserting into the database.

Comment: You have to escape the text from the textarea using mysql_real_escape

Comment: @mrTux thankyou for your input. i have posted what i think to be the answer

Answer (score 0):

I see your code sends submited data to another page, i checked it through `print_r($_POST)`

I changed `<form action="post.php" method="POST">` to `<form action="" method="POST">` and tried and it was working, in case if the code you submited here is not "post.php" do this.

So it means someting is wrong with your insert query. So try this PDO way of inserting data.I thought of suggesting you the following easy pdo insert

```
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "mydatabase";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "mypppasss";
    //connection string
    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbusername,$dbpassword);
```

Inside the if($content) put the following code and try

```
$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO post(userID,post_date,postContent)
    VALUES(:inp1,:inp2,:inp3,:inp4)");
$statement->execute(array(
    inp1=>$_SESSION["userID"],
    inp2=>$post_date,
    inp4=>$content
));
```

EDITED

Add this code to the form submitted page to see the posted data for debugging.

```
if($_POST){
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
}
```

EDITED

> Note:@ is used to hide errors, prevent it from displaying error
>   messages. that doesn't mean there is no error. Remove @ for debugging

EDITED
Change your whole insert query part to this and try

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO post(userID,post_date,in_reply_to,postContent)
VALUES (".$_SESSION['userID'].",".$post_date.",'',".$content.")";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "inserted";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Hmmm, i appreciate the help. But that didnt work either. 
It seems like the "if($content){" part is being skipped over entirely, which includes the mysql_query. Because it isnt coming up with an error saying the query failed, it just isnt even trying it.

Comment: is that all in one php file and is that all?

Comment: The above code is all in one php file, it connects through a sperate file 'connect.php'.

Comment: I dont know what i have done wrong. Because iam using this in a forum website for an assignment, and i have a page called "register.php" that people can put in their information and it creates a user, and it works fine, inserts into the database with no worries. 
and i used the exact same way to do it with this but it wont do it.

Comment: It might just be me .. but since when can you write @$_POST and @$_SESSION ? .. and not just $_POST etc ?

Comment: did print_r($_POST) return anything? btw why are you using @$_POST and @$_SESSION, just use $_SESSION and $_POST

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: con in C:\wamp\www\post.php on line 35

When taken from "$content = @$_POST['con'];"

Comment: that means con is not defined

Comment: that means your connection string is not defined

Comment: in that case see my answer. use the connection string that i mentioned above.

Comment: $link is the connection string here

Comment: if i use $content = @$_POST['con']; it has no error, and is defined

Comment: @30088121 Edited my answer see the last past. it should work now :)

Comment: @ is used to hide errors, prevent it from displaying error messages. that doesn't mean there is no error.

Comment: @aimme i changed to to not use the '@' and i still have the same problem.

Comment: can you show the connect.php file. remove username and password before posting :)

Comment: <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",'sitedata') or die ("couldnt connect to database");
?>

Comment: Thats all thats in the connect.php file

Comment: It all works fine for the register page where data also has to be inserted into the DB. But just not this, so frustrating me.

Comment: so for debugging add that $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",'sitedata') or die ("couldnt connect to database"); above your mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO post(`postID`, `userID`  ...

Comment: I gave that a go, it didnt help.

Comment: @30088121 edited my answer, if postID is auto increment primary key so remove it from query. remove (`) this from column names and try.

Comment: So i have found what was making it skip, i had "require('connect.php'); " up the very top, and this section of code was in different <?php> tags so i added "require('connect.php')" to it so it re established the connection i assume

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It should work.

```
<?php
session_start();
require('connect.php');
if(@$_SESSION["name"]){
    //echo "welcome ".$_SESSION['name'];
 ?>
  <html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<head>
<title> Welcome to faecesbook</title>
</head>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <form action="post.php" method="POST">
        <br / >
        <br / >
        <br / >
        <br / >
    <center>
        <br/> 
        <br/>
        Type your post here:<br/>(160CharLimit)<br/>
        <textarea style="resize: none;  width: 800px; height: 100px;" name="con" maxlength="160">
       </textarea>
                     <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" style="width: 800px;" >
    </center>   
    </form>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<?php       
$post_date = date("d-m-y");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['con']) && $_POST['con'] != ''){
           $content = @$_POST['con'];
            if($query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO post(`postID`, `userID`   , `post_date` , `in_reply_to`, `postContent` ) 
            VALUES ('','".$_SESSION["userID"]."','".$post_date."','','".$content."')") )
            echo "post successful";
    }else{
            echo "post fail";
    }   

}else{
        echo "Please include some content";
}
}

  ?>
```

Comment: if(isset($_POST['con']) && $_POST['con'] != ''){

}

This checks for blank field in text.

Comment: While this is a better way to write, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The code works fine for me. I have commented the connection.php and header.php inclusion. Also commented "if(@$_SESSION["name"])". Post functionality works perfectly well. You need to provide other details so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing braces in your code

```
if(@$_SESSION["name"]){
    //echo "welcome ".$_SESSION['name'];
```

Should read

```
if(@$_SESSION["name"]){
    //echo "welcome ".$_SESSION['name'];
}
```

And

```
if($query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO post(`postID`, `userID`   , `post_date` , `in_reply_to`, `postContent` )
    VALUES ('','".$_SESSION["userID"]."','".$post_date."','','".$content."')") ) // <--- here
            echo "post successful";
        }else{
            echo "post fail";
}
```

Making it readable also helps reduce errors

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO post(`postID`, `userID`   , `post_date` , `in_reply_to`, `postContent` )
    VALUES ('','".$_SESSION["userID"]."','".$post_date."','','".$content."')");

if ($query){
    echo "post successful";
}else{
    echo "post fail";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what was wrong.
i had two set of `<?php ?>`, the first one in the code included `require('connect.php');` within it, and the second one required it also.

```
<?php       
require('connect.php'); <<<<<------ NEEDED TO ADD THIS
$content = @$_POST['con'];
$post_date = date("d-m-y");
$userID = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT userID FROM users WHERE name = '".$_SESSION['name']."'");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($content){
        if($query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO post(`postID`, `userID` , `post_date` , `in_reply_to`, `postContent` ) 
        VALUES ('','".$userID."','".$post_date."','','".$content."')") )
            echo "post successful";
        }else{
            echo "post fail";
}   

    }else{
        echo "Please include some content";
}
}

?>
```

So thats what i think the offending piece of code was. And it now will give me error saying the SQLI query was unnsuccessful, which means it is at least attempting that part, whereas before it was not.